# Lombok Setter, set input variable to be final

Tags: java, lombok

Is is possible using lombok to set the input variable of a @Setter method to be final.

For example

```
public void setCarName(final String carName){
   this.carName = carName;
}
```

I don't know if this is even possible could not see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's not possible.

The only advantage of making `final` this parameter is to improve readability, which makes no sense on code that will not be read.

Comment: Above code was only an example, but I get what you and other answers mean. Thanks

Comment: making input parameter final for all setters will help make a class immutable. That is an important usecase.

Comment: No, it won't. The fact that the parameter is final doesn't mean you cannot use it to modify the status of the object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, just checked lombok sources.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even be worried about this? Making it final only prevents you from reinitializing the variable, i.e. `carName = "foo"` or `carName = new String("foo")`. Since the code generated by lombok does not attempt to do this marking it as final is completely unneccesary.